# how to convert a stored procedure with parameters to a ETL and load data to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working a task that I need convert a complicate stored procedure to a ETL but the intricacy here is that, the SP has five parameters, so how should I convert the SP to a ETL and load data to a table in DW?

Comment: Do you mean to say 5 input parameters ?

Comment: Because the SP is executed using those parameters, so I'm not quite sure about how to map the result table in SP to the destination table in DW without those paramters

Comment: What does "convert the SP to a ETL" even mean?   What is your desired result?

Comment: Because there is a temp table in the SP and I want map the temp table to a table in DW

Answer (score 0):

I would use Merge script to load data into DW,I  can write Merge scripts if u like.

Answer (score 0):

Use this proc, it should work. Getting results from Sp into a temp table and merge using temp table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_ETLJOB
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp1 (
        col1 INT
        ,col2 INT
        ,col3 INT
        ,col4 INT
        )

    INSERT INTO #temp1
    EXEC usp_Inputproc @1
        ,@2
        ,@3
        ,@4;

    MERGE Destination AS target
    USING #Temp1 AS source
        ON target.col1(id) = source.col1(id)
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET target.col1 = source.col1
                ,target.col2 = source.col2
                , target.col3 = source.col3
                , target.col4 = source.col4
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT (
                col1
                ,col2
                ,col3
                , col4
                )
            VALUES (
                source.col1
                ,source.col2
                ,source.col3
                ,source.col4
                )
END
```

I have selected INT as data type, you can use any data type as in target table